# Trying to place label inline with button group in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have inherited the development of a website. I need to change a Bootstrap input form to a more compact layout and therefore I have tried to modify the code in order to show a label inline with a button group (instead of over the button group). I fail on this one and I can't understand the strange behaviour.

The code below (also available at https://jsfiddle.net/ewdt76zc/10/) shows two different forms. The first one show a label and three buttons below the label. In the second one I hoped to let the label and button group share the same line. But it fails and the three buttons are pushed extremely to the right and are really minimized... Strange!

I would like to achieve the following layout:

`Company: [  Apple  ][ Microsoft ][  Google  ]`

What's wrong and how can I solve it?

```
<p><i>(label above radio buttons)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Company</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<p><i>(label inline with radio buttons... buttons are compact to the right?)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label>Company</label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using specific percentages we can achieve the desired layout.

For demo purpose i created `demo-1` & `demo-2` classes. Applied specific width in percentages to that classes and appended that classes to the `label` & `btn-group`.

```css
.demo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.demo-2 {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left !important;
  width: 90% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p><i>(label above radio buttons)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Company</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<p><i>(label inline with radio buttons... buttons are compact to the right?)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="demo1">Company</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified demo-2" data-toggle="buttons">
     
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the class "form-inline" (or "form-horizontal") to your radio buttons form.

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display:flex` to `form group` and add margin to labels of your choice as required. hope it is helpful to you.

```css
.form-group {
 display: flex;
}

label {
 margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><i>(label above radio buttons)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Company</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<p><i>(label inline with radio buttons... buttons are compact to the right?)</i></p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label>Company</label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Apple
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Microsoft
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default form-control">
        <input type="radio">Google
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```